# "The token could not be parsed from the request" in jwt in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, angular

I am facing **"The token could not be parsed from the request"** error in JWT in Laravel.

I have tried same code in localhost(Xampp in windows 7) it is working but on server it is not working.

I have passed **"Authorization"** token in header and also changed **.htaccess** file.

Please check below screenshot for passed token in request in angular 2.

[image]

Below is **.htaccess** file. (I have also tried this code in root .htaccess file and public .htaccess file both)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
```

And I have used below code for authenticated token.

```
public function image_upload(Request $request){
    try{
        if($user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()){
            \Api::success(['data' => $user]);
        }else{
            \Api::error("User is not found.");
        }
    }
    catch(\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e){
        \Api::error(['type'=> 'expired','message' => 'Your login has been expired. Please login and try again.']);
        exit();
    }
    catch(\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e){
        \Api::error(['type'=> 'invalid','message' => $e->getMessage()]);
        exit();
    }
    catch(\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e){
        \Api::error(['type'=> 'invalid','message' => $e->getMessage()]);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try to return `$request->bearerToken()` and see if you can have it?

Comment: Furthermore, an issue is stated here maybe its related to your case? https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/786 i.e ```# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]```

Comment: I have tried $request->bearerToken() it is returning *NULL*  value

Comment: I have changed **.htaccess** file but, I am getting same error.

Comment: Did you compare your changes with the one stated in the issue? seems there is a bit of differences.

Comment: incase you need to save time fixing this, you can simply pass the token as a parameter in your request i.e `http://somehost.come/alien/?token=theTokenHere`

Comment: Ok, Thanks, But I have used same code in my locallost it is working file but when i uploading on server then I am getting this error

Comment: I have passed Token in Request but still i am getting same error

Comment: can you return your requests i.e `return request->token` if you have anything? did you add it to the request parameter?

Comment: Yes, I am getting token in request

Comment: If you are getting the token, then attempt the answer I just gave and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the problematic exclusion of the `Authorization` header by Apache, then if you need to save time you can pass the token into your requests, then in your controller, check if you have the token with:

```
public function image_upload(Request $request){
    return $request->token;
.....
}
```

Did you have any result? if you don't then you have to check if your request parameter has the `token` field. If you have the token in this controller, then you can still use the `parseToken()` method or simply (maybe for debugging purpose) use:

```
public function image_upload(Request $request){
    $user = JWTAuth::toUser($request->token));
    .......
}
```

I think this should be sufficient, the only mistake might be that you have applied a `middleware` that is causing this issue to the route you are accessing.

> PS: I tried this on Laravel 5.2*

I hope this helps.

Comment: you're right, it works when passing the token in body (post method) but not sure how to make it work when passing it via header authorization bearer.. your recommendation is appreciated!