# After hit the logout endpoint its showing "401 Unauthorized". Do you know why?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I was doing some requests to an API using jwt and it was working fine. Then, I created a logout endpoint and did a POST request to this endpoint like "http://app.test/api/logout/".

It worked and it showed "'Logout'" according to the code below:

```
public function logout()
    {
        try {
            auth('api')->logout();

            return response()->json([
                'msg' => 'Logout'
            ], 200);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I did a request again to the login endpoint to get a new jwt. However, now when I try to do requests to the other endpoints, that were working fine before the logout request like a get request to get all posts "http://app.test/api/posts/", it shows always this error:

```
"message": "Wrong number of segments",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\UnauthorizedHttpException",
```

The Api Routes are under the 'jwt.auth' middleware:

```
Route::post('login', [JwtController::class, 'login'])
->name('login');

Route::post('logout', [JwtController::class, 'logout'])
->name('logout');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
...
}
```

If I remove from the headers the Accept key with application/json, it shows `401 not authorised` instead of the invalid number of segments.

Do you know what can be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: That is a token error. Check that your Auth headers contain the correct token.

Comment: Yes, I just hit the login endpoint to get a new token, then try to access the get endpoint but it shows always that error. In the headers I have the Authentication key and the value as Bearer and then the token. Thanks!

Comment: Try doing the login and log out a couple of times and make sure the token changes. Do you have anyway to check the current token?

Comment: Well, when I hit the login endpoint I get a new token. In postman is possible to check the current token? It should be the token generated with the last login hit no? Thanks

Comment: You would think so. But somethings going wrong with the token somewhere. Best to check it all.

Comment: Its was showing the wrong segments error because I was also sending on the headers an Accept key with application/json. Now it returns a 401 not authorised.

Comment: So that should be right then if you are logged out.

Comment: But I logged in, received a new token and using the new token never works.

Comment: If I hit the logout endpoint appears always "{
    "error": "Token could not be parsed from the request."
}".

Comment: ,look at this now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363316/the-token-could-not-be-parsed-from-the-request-in-jwt-in-laravel

Comment: If I have this "        dd($request->bearerToken());
" on the logout endpoint it shows the correctly the last generated token on the login endpoint. However if I remove "        dd($request->bearerToken());
" from the logout endpoint it shows always "{"error":"Token could not be parsed from the request."}".

Comment: what web server are you using? e.g. apache, nginx etc